# Instances of interactions between partners

Tags: r, unique, tidyverse, dplyr

Research context: *speakers* (writers) and *recipients* interact in written communication concerning a certain discussion *topic*. The first speaker is the original person who posted a *thread*.

Data look like:

```
structure(list(topic = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2), thread = c(1, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3), speaker_id = c(111, 111, 111, 222, 222, 
222, 111, 222), recipient_id = c(222, 333, 444, 111, 555, 444, 
222, 111), dyad = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("111_222", 
"111_333", "111_444", "222_444", "222_555"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), codepage = 65001L)
```

The aims are creating two variables:

1. **threads_partnered**: In how many threads within a discussion topic were the speaker and recipient partnered (i.e., made a dyad or directly interacted)?
2. **threads_present**: In how many threads--other than the given thread--within a discussion topic were the speaker and recipient present as recipients, without being partnered (or forming a dyad)?

Based on the example data, the results would look like:

```
╔═══════╦════════╦═════════╦═══════════╦═════════╦═══════════╦══════════════════════════════════════════╦═════════╦════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ topic ║ thread ║ speaker ║ recipient ║   dyad  ║  threads  ║                   note                   ║ threads ║                    note                    ║
║       ║        ║    id   ║     id    ║         ║ partnered ║                                          ║ present ║                                            ║
╠═══════╬════════╬═════════╬═══════════╬═════════╬═══════════╬══════════════════════════════════════════╬═════════╬════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║  1.00 ║    1   ║   111   ║    222    ║ 111_222 ║     2     ║ 111 and 222 interacted (made a dyad)     ║    0    ║ Outside the given thread (thread #1) of    ║
║       ║        ║         ║           ║         ║           ║ in two different threads (thread #1, #2) ║         ║ the given topic (topic #1), 111 and 222    ║
║       ║        ║         ║           ║         ║           ║ within topic 1                           ║         ║ are not found together as recipients       ║
║       ║        ║         ║           ║         ║           ║                                          ║         ║ other than being in a dyad                 ║
╠═══════╬════════╬═════════╬═══════════╬═════════╬═══════════╬══════════════════════════════════════════╬═════════╬════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║  1.00 ║    1   ║   111   ║    333    ║ 111_333 ║     1     ║ 111 and 333 interacted in                ║    0    ║                                            ║
║       ║        ║         ║           ║         ║           ║ one thread (thread #1)                   ║         ║                                            ║
╠═══════╬════════╬═════════╬═══════════╬═════════╬═══════════╬══════════════════════════════════════════╬═════════╬════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║  1.00 ║    1   ║   111   ║    444    ║ 111_444 ║     1     ║ 111 and 444 interacted in                ║    1    ║ 111 and 444 are found in thread #2,        ║
║       ║        ║         ║           ║         ║           ║ one thread (thread #1)                   ║         ║ where they did not interact (made a dyad), ║
║       ║        ║         ║           ║         ║           ║                                          ║         ║ but were only recipients of                ║
║       ║        ║         ║           ║         ║           ║                                          ║         ║ the original speaker (111)                 ║
╠═══════╬════════╬═════════╬═══════════╬═════════╬═══════════╬══════════════════════════════════════════╬═════════╬════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║  1.00 ║    2   ║   222   ║    111    ║ 111_222 ║     2     ║ 111 and 222 interacted in two different  ║    0    ║                                            ║
║       ║        ║         ║           ║         ║           ║ threads within topic 1                   ║         ║                                            ║
╠═══════╬════════╬═════════╬═══════════╬═════════╬═══════════╬══════════════════════════════════════════╬═════════╬════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║  1.00 ║    2   ║   222   ║    555    ║ 222_555 ║     1     ║ 222 and 555 interacted in one thread     ║    0    ║                                            ║
╠═══════╬════════╬═════════╬═══════════╬═════════╬═══════════╬══════════════════════════════════════════╬═════════╬════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║  1.00 ║    2   ║   222   ║    444    ║ 222_444 ║     1     ║ 222 and 444 interacted in one thread     ║    1    ║ 222 and 444 are found together             ║
║       ║        ║         ║           ║         ║           ║                                          ║         ║ in thread #1, where they did not           ║
║       ║        ║         ║           ║         ║           ║                                          ║         ║ interact                                   ║
╠═══════╬════════╬═════════╬═══════════╬═════════╬═══════════╬══════════════════════════════════════════╬═════════╬════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║  2.00 ║    3   ║   111   ║    222    ║ 111_222 ║     1     ║ 111 and 222 interacted in one thread     ║    0    ║                                            ║
║       ║        ║         ║           ║         ║           ║ (thread 3) within topic 2                ║         ║                                            ║
╠═══════╬════════╬═════════╬═══════════╬═════════╬═══════════╬══════════════════════════════════════════╬═════════╬════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║  2.00 ║    3   ║   222   ║    111    ║ 111_222 ║     1     ║ same as above                            ║    0    ║                                            ║
╚═══════╩════════╩═════════╩═══════════╩═════════╩═══════════╩══════════════════════════════════════════╩═════════╩════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: Can you show the calculation

Comment: @akrun Thank you, Akrun. I added notes in the table explaining what the calculation look like in my mind. Does it make sense to you? Let me know if it is not clear!

Comment: I think your first column output is `df1 %>% group_by(topic, dyad) %>% mutate(threds_partnered = n_distinct(thread))`, 2nd I didn't udnerstsand

Comment: @akrun Thank you! I will edit it clearer. Whereas the aim of the first one (thread_partnered) is to get the number of threads that two people had "direct" interactions, forming an actual dyad; the second was about the number of threads where two people had "indirect" interactions, where they were listed as recipients but did not form a dyad with each other in that thread(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure this accomplishes what you need, but perhaps it might be helpful in some way.

I created a custom function to take the speaker, recipient, thread, and topic, and determine the `threads_present` based on your description. This includes looking at other `thread`s within the same `topic`, checking to make sure the other `thread`s don't contain the speaker and recipient as a `dyad`. Finally, the `thread` should include *both* a speaker and recipient as a recipient in some row. These `thread`s are then counted.

The second `threads_partnered` is more straightforward and described in the comments. After you `group_by` both `topic` and `dyad` you can determine the number of unique `thread`s with `n_distinct`.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

my_fun <- function(the_speaker, the_recipient, the_thread, the_topic) {
  df %>%
    filter(
      topic == the_topic,
      thread != the_thread, 
      dyad != paste(min(the_speaker, the_recipient), max(the_speaker, the_recipient), sep = "_")) %>%
    group_by(thread) %>%
    filter(all(c(the_speaker, the_recipient) %in% recipient_id)) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    distinct(thread) %>%
    count(name = "threads_present")
}

df %>%
  mutate(threads_present = pmap(
    list(the_speaker = speaker_id, the_recipient = recipient_id, the_thread = thread, the_topic = topic),
    my_fun)
  ) %>%
  unnest(cols = threads_present) %>%
  group_by(topic, dyad) %>%
  mutate(threads_partnered = n_distinct(thread))
```

**Output**

```
  topic thread speaker_id recipient_id dyad    threads_present threads_partnered
  <dbl>  <dbl>      <dbl>        <dbl> <fct>             <int>             <int>
1     1      1        111          222 111_222               0                 2
2     1      1        111          333 111_333               0                 1
3     1      1        111          444 111_444               1                 1
4     1      2        222          111 111_222               0                 2
5     1      2        222          555 222_555               0                 1
6     1      2        222          444 222_444               1                 1
7     2      3        111          222 111_222               0                 1
8     2      3        222          111 111_222               0                 1
```